# Read from a web page and using two determiner for new row and next cell in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to read from a feed webpage which its structure is something like

A,B,C;E,F,G;....

I want to read this data and put A B  and C in the first row and put E F and G in row 2, and etc.

I was looking for a function in VBA, but most of them are for only one determiner.

I also was thinking of using string functions of VBA, which that would be the last resort! Since I must read a long string and then use a cursor (which  I don't know if it is like c or not!) that probably leads to unstable performance because first I don't know the volume of data, and second I want to use it in a loop.

Could you please help me with the best solution?

Comment: Does `A,B,C;E,F,G` represent a string that you want to parse into columns and rows?

Answer (score 2):

```
feed = "A,B,C;E,F,G;...."

CSV = Replace( feed, ";", vbNewLine )
TSV = Replace( CSV , ",", vbTab )

Set do = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}") ' this is a late bound MSForms.DataObject
do.SetText TSV
do.PutInClipboard

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Very Nice!  I seen that once before but forgot about it.  Kudos

Comment: @Thomas Inzina I just rather not explain how to add reference to MSForms :] BTW the easier way for me is to add form control to any sheet and delete it

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    ParseString1 "A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I,J,K,L"
    ParseString2 "A,B,C;D,E,F;G,H,I,J,K,L"

End Sub

Sub ParseString1(data As String)
    Dim clip As MSForms.DataObject
    Set clip = New MSForms.DataObject

    data = Replace(data, ",", vbTab)
    data = Replace(data, ";", vbCrLf)

    clip.SetText data
    clip.PutInClipboard

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

End Sub

Sub ParseString2(data As String)
    Dim aColumns, aRows
    Dim x As Long
    aRows = Split(data, ";")

    For x = 0 To UBound(aRows)
        aColumns = Split(aRows(x), ",")
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, UBound(aColumns) + 1) = aColumns
    Next

End Sub
```

You'll need to set a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library if you use ParseString1.

[image]